# active record: create record from parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

this is what I mean:

job has many docs. I want to create a doc, I can do:

```
@doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
```

but I'd like to enforce the parent-child relationship, since I already know the job.. something like this:

```
@job.docs.new(params[:doc])
```

so that the job_id field gets ignored and only the @job object matters...

does it make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `build` method:

```
@job.docs.build(params[:doc])
```

See the [has_many api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833) or the [Rails Guide for associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) for a list of methods available on the collection.

Answer (score 4):

```
# initialize the object
@job.docs.build(params[:doc])
# create the object
@job.docs.create(params[:doc])
```

Comment: To be clear, the difference is that "create" goes ahead and inserts the new object into the database.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you've specified the relationship in the model, Job will [automagically have a build method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference):

```
@job.docs.build(params[:doc])
```